# Time stamp when multiple cells in a row are changed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have been trying to use a macro to time stamp cells in a column, when another cell in that row is changed, the below which I got from another thread here works perfectly.

However I want to do the same, but this time if any cell in the row changes.
I added an additional column which combines all other entries in the row by a simple "&" formula, but it seems the below doesn't work when a formula cell is updated.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    WatchedColumn = 2
    BlockedRow = 1
    TimestampColumn = 4
    Crow = Target.Row
    CColumn = Target.Column
    If CColumn = WatchedColumn And Crow > BlockedRow Then
            Cells(Crow, TimestampColumn) = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use the *Calculate* event rather than the *Worksheet_Change* event.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the additional information provided I think I might have a viable solution for you.  I thought about editing my original answer but it is pretty drastically changed so thought it might be more helpful to just provide a new one.  At first glance it might look long and drawn out but remove the comments and it is much less "cumbersome."  I've commented it somewhat extensively just to provide better clarity.

```
'global variable for the original value
Dim old_Value As Variant

'on select change event is used to trap original value of the cell being changed
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'check to see if it is a single cell or multiple cells
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        'check if cell is in appropriate range
        If Target.Row < 6 And Target.Column = 1 Then

            'set original value of the cell to the global "old_Value" variable
            old_Value = Target.Value
        End If

    'if more than one cell is being updated (dragging, ctrl-enter, etc.)
    Else

        'set value of old value to concatenation of original values
        For i = 1 To 5
            old_Value = old_Value & Cells(i, 1)
        Next
    End If
End Sub


'on change event is used to compare the values of the old cell vs the new cell
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Integer            'variable for for loop (if needed)
    Dim new_Value As String     'variable for storing new values concatenation (if needed)

    'check to see if it is a single cell or multiple cells
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        'make sure cell is in appropriate row and column range and compare old value to new value
        If Target.Row < 6 And Target.Column = 1 And old_Value <> Target.Value Then

            'if change happened set timestamp
            Cells(6, 1) = Now()
        End If

    'if more than one cell is being updated (dragging, ctrl-enter, etc.)
    Else

        'concatenate new values into one variable
        For i = 1 To 5
            new_Value = new_Value & Cells(i, 1)
        Next

        'compare new with old and set timestamp if appropriate
        If new_Value <> old_Value Then
            Cells(6, 1) = Now()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I cannot definitively say this is the BEST way to do it but it works for what you described.  Hopefully you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be interpreting what you want to do correctly; however, if I am, there is a way to do it using a global variable to store the original cell value.  On the SelectionChange event set the global value (old_Value) = target value and then you can use this to compare cell values and update the timestamp as appropriate in the Worksheet_Change event.

```
Dim old_Value As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   TimestampColumn = 4
   Ccolumn = Target.Column
   Crow = Target.Row

   If old_Value <> Cells(Crow, Ccolumn) Then
      Cells(Crow, TimestampColumn) = Now()
   End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   old_Value = Target.Value
End Sub
```

I should probably add the caveat that this will throw an error if you are selecting a range or dragging a cell value through multiple cells (row or column) at once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have no idea what to do with it...
To explain this better see below:
I have some data in A1:A5, I want to have a time-stamp populate in A6 when any of the values in A1:A5 are changed.
The macro I posted above works but only when one cell is changed, for example A1 is changed so A6 gets a time stamp. 
I've tried to put in the same macro twice also changing the watched column, but it doesn't do anything.
The last thing I tried is to add a new column lets say A7 with the formula (=A1&A2&A3&A4&A5) and then have this be the watched column but it also doesn't work